# libGDX load tiled map from string

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

I currenly load my tiled map from assets folder.

```
TiledMap tileMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("assets/level1.tmx");
```

But I want to make something like level of the day.
Is it possible to load a tiled map from a string?

A string would be the content of a .tmx file.

Example http://pastebin.com/WpV90Hma

Comment: Nope, but you could save the data to a file and load from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to create a (temporary) `FileHandle` with the content and use that to load the map.

By default `TmxMapLoader` will use an `InternalFileHandleResolver`. This won't work, because you cannot create internal files at runtime.

That's why you would instead use an `ExternalFileHandleResolver` for the map loader, create an external file and write your map of the day as a string into it.

```
String mapOfTheDay = ...;
FileHandle mapOfTheDayFile = Gdx.files.external("mygame/mapoftheday.tmx");
mapOfTheDayFile.writeString(mapOfTheDay, false);
TiledMap tileMap = new TmxMapLoader(new ExternalFileHandleResolver()).load("mygame/mapoftheday.tmx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting and rewriting methods from TmxLoader, I am able to load a map from a XML String: http://pastebin.com/gQHQv6eV

!! BUT !!, this is *very* crappy and only loads really basics TMX files. It can be continued to load complex TMX but I dont need it for now.

Files referenced by the TMX (tilesets...) must be in your app working directory.